# wget log format meaning

Tags: wget

I fetch a online video with wget on Linux. May I ask the log format meaning of its downloading process as following? What does the #s at the end of each line intend to say?

Thank you!

```
     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  2% 79.6K 26s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4%  317K 16s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  7% 10.9M 10s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9%  322K 9s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11% 11.5M 7s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 14%  327K 7s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16% 10.8M 6s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 19% 11.6M 5s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 21%  338K 5s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23% 10.8M 4s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 11.4M 4s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 28% 11.0M 3s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 31%  347K 3s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 33% 10.8M 3s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35% 11.6M 3s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 38% 10.9M 2s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 40% 11.5M 2s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 43% 10.9M 2s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45%  373K 2s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 47% 11.4M 2s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 50% 10.9M 2s
  1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52% 11.5M 1s
  1100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 55% 11.0M 1s
  1150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57% 11.3M 1s
  1200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59% 11.7M 1s
  1250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 62% 10.8M 1s
  1300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 64% 11.6M 1s
  1350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 67%  412K 1s
  1400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69% 10.7M 1s
  1450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 71% 40.1K 1s
  1500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 74% 35.8K 2s
  1550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 76% 35.8K 2s
  1600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79% 11.0M 2s
  1650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 81% 35.8K 2s
  1700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 83% 35.8K 2s
  1750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 86% 35.8K 2s
  1800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 88% 11.0M 1s
  1850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90% 35.8K 1s
  1900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 93% 35.8K 1s
  1950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 95% 35.8K 1s
  2000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98% 54.5K 0s
  2050K .......... .......... .......... ........             100% 11.5M=15s
```

Answer (score 1):

They simply represent the time remaining before the download ends, right after the download speed, and the percentage done.

Comment: why does the downloading rate fluctuate so diversely?

Comment: Well I guess it depends on your server or the remote server you're downloading from.